# Django Formset Issue On Select Field and Saving?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I would like to use a formset for editing all the records in a model 'Category'. And I would like to know how to fix two issues:

1. Currently it populates all fields with initial data, except input
   select for 'Language' and input select for 'Parent'.
2. It does not save on submit.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ORDER = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'))
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=ORDER)
    allow_replies = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

# Forms
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['language', 'name', 'parent', 'allow_replies', 'order']
```

**views.py**

```
def category_formset(request):
    if is_admin_user(request):
        CategoryFormSet = formset_factory(CategoryForm)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = CategoryFormSet(request.POST)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
        else:
            formset = CategoryFormSet(initial=Category.objects.values())
        return render_to_response("pages/category_formset.html",
                                  {"formset": formset, 'is_logged_in': is_logged_in(request)},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return redirect('/', False)
```

**html template**

```
<form action="/category/edit/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Language</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Parent</td>
            <td>Allow Replies</td>
            <td>Order</td>
        </tr>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <tr>
            {% for item in form %}
                <td>{{ item }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Small tip: use modelfomset_factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

**MODEL**

```
# ...
def category_formset(request):
    if is_admin_user(request):
        CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Category, exclude="slug", extra=0)

        if request.POST:
            formset = CategoryFormSet(request.POST)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return redirect('/categories/')
        else:
            formset = CategoryFormSet(initial=Category.objects.values())
        return render_to_response("pages/category_formset.html",
                                  {"formset": formset, 'is_logged_in': is_logged_in(request)},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return redirect('/', False)
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<form action="/category/edit/" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.errors }}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Language</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Parent</td>
            <td>Allow Replies</td>
            <td>Order</td>
        </tr>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <tr>
            {% for item in form %}
                <td>{{ item }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```